How do I efficiently identify sub-sequences in a partial TSP solution?
Assume I have a TSP over $n$ nodes. Assume I get a partial solution which contains only some of the $n\times n$, $x_{ij}$ variables. For example, assume I have a TSP with $10$ nodes. I get a partial solution with

$x_{3,2}=1$
$x_{5,6}=1$
$x_{2,8}=1$
$x_{8,1}=1$
$x_{6,10}=1$

This indicates I have two sub-sequences (not to be confused with subtours): $3\to 2\to 8\to 1$ and $5\to 6\to 10$.
Note, for example, that I do not know anything about nodes $7$ and $4$ and $9$, and this is fine.
Question: Is there any known efficient procedure that allows me to identify such sub-sequences?

Do you ask to know how to identify the subtours?

@A.Omidi, no, not subtouts, but partial, incomplete sequences, similar to the ones I have in the example. Not tours, but simple sequences of nodes.

I guess you are interested in a combination of:

connected components (linear-time)
topological sorting (linear-time)
(cycle detection)

iff you obtained a cycle (e.g. complete solution, missing subtour-elimination)



Consider doing something like the following (this is python using networkx (graph-lib)):
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(5,6)
G.add_edge(2,8)
G.add_edge(8,1)
G.add_edge(6,10)
# G.add_edge(10, 5)  # implies cycle -> we will run exception branch below!

# Need undirected graph for connected components
uG = G.to_undirected()
components = list(nx.connected_components(uG))
print('components: ', components)

# Need (node-)subgraph to run topological-sort on each component
for component in components:
  sG = G.subgraph(component)
  try:
    sequence_when_acyclic = nx.topological_sort(sG)
    print('acyclic: ', list(sequence_when_acyclic))
  except nx.exception.NetworkXUnfeasible:
    cycle = list(nx.simple_cycles(sG))  # we do this to somehow keep 'orientation' / maybe overkill
    assert len(cycle) == 1
    print('cyclic: ', cycle[0])

With your data (no cycle):
components:  [{8, 1, 2, 3}, {10, 5, 6}]
acyclic:  [3, 2, 8, 1]
acyclic:  [5, 6, 10]

With an additional cycle-inducing edge (see outcommented edge):
components:  [{8, 1, 2, 3}, {10, 5, 6}]
acyclic:  [3, 2, 8, 1]
cyclic:  [10, 5, 6]

I don't know your use-case, but i should mention, that the CP-community provides some more interesting deduction-possibilities in this setting IF you are interested:

Francis, Kathryn Glenn, and Peter J. Stuckey. "Explaining circuit propagation." Constraints 19 (2014): 1-29.


You can do this pretty easily in most programming languages, particularly object-oriented languages with some version of "sequence" and "map". (I'm thinking of Java, with a List structure for the sequence and Map structure for the map.)
Create two initially empty maps, one mapping a point to a potential path starting there, the other mapping a point to a potential path ending there. Now process each arc $(i,j)$ whose binary variable is 1 as follows.

If the first map contains an entry $j \rightarrow P$ (so $P$ starts at $j$) and the second map contains an entry $i \rightarrow P'$ (so $P'$ ends at $i$), create a new path $P'' = P' - (i,j) - P$. Find the starting point $m$ of $P'$ and the ending point $n$ of $P$, and add $m \rightarrow P''$ to the first map and $n \rightarrow P''$ to the second map (replacing the previous entries). Move to the next arc.
If the second map contains an entry $i \rightarrow P$ (where $P$ is a path ending at $i$), extend $P$ by adding $(i,j)$ at its end, delete the entry in the second map and add an entry $j \rightarrow P$ in the second map (since the path now ends at $j$). Leave the entry for the path in the first map alone (the starting point has not changed). Move to the next arc.
If the first map contains an entry $j \rightarrow P$ (where $P$ is a path beginning at $j$), extend $P$ by adding $(i,j)$ at its start, delete the entry int the first map and add an entry $i \rightarrow P$ in the first map (since $P$ now starts at $i$). Leave the entry for the path in the second map alone. Move to the next arc.
If we get here, $(i,j)$ does not extend an existing path at either end. Turn it into a new path $P$ and add entries $i \rightarrow P$ in the first map and $j \rightarrow P$ in the second map.

